# MS Access - issue when copypasting table with dropdowns

Tags: ms-access

I have an absurd problem when I try to copy table from one Database to another.
Say I have a database with table containing drop-down list for all its records.

Not sure if it matters, but the table is populated with data submitted by users via   Excel macro. When the user submits the record, it's pushed to this Database with attributes chosen by the user from drop-down cells.

**The problem:**

When I copy and paste this table from source data into other database, all attributes are missing. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afi64.png) is how the table looks in source data. And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbPnf.png) is how this table looks after its pasted in another database. When pasting, I choose *structure and data* option.

I don't even know where to begin fixing it and why it happens. What's strange, it worked just fine couple of days ago and old submits are pasted correctly.

Comment: I guess those attributes are coming from the _Attributes_ table.  When  you copy the data from _Profiles_ you're just copying the data held in that table.  There's a relationship between the _Profiles_ and _Attributes_ table which is how you see the drop-down.  Try copying the _Attributes_ data as well - make backups of your database before attempting just in case. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, thank you so much! That was it.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database has a relationship built between the *Profiles* table and the *Attributes* table.  You should be able to see this by clicking on the *Relationships* button in the *Database Tools* menu.

By the looks of it your `Profiles.ID` field will be related to an `Attributes.ProfileID` field (i.e. the `Profiles.ID` field is listed in all related records in the `Attributes` table).

Your newly copied `Profiles` data doesn't have any related data in the `Attributes` table.  When you copy that data over your table should appear as expected - with the little `+` icon revealing the related records.